# Ruby Snytax to Achieve this SQL Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a RoR Webapp which is a dashboard . For this i need to perform a INNER JOIN of 2 tables before performing a COUNT of the result

How do i write this in Ruby Syntax using Active Record

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks 
  INNER JOIN feedback_categories ON feedbacks.id=feedback_categories.feedback_id 
  WHERE feedback_categories.category_id=1
```

The two tables are feedbacks and feedback_categories.? Any pointers will be helpful .

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins:

```
Feedback.joins(:feedback_category).where(:feedback_categories => {:category_id => 1}).count
```

Note that feedback_category in joins and in where clause could be pluralized differently depending on your relationship. Inside of where it will always be pluralized, in joins it could be singular.

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

this will help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model called Feedback, just use that:

```
Feedback.count :conditions => "feedback_categories.category_id = 1",
               :joins => "INNER JOIN feedback_categories ON feedbacks.id=feedback_categories.feedback_id"
```